# Execute python in PHP and get response as i get in terminal

Tags: php, python, apache, shell-exec

i am new to PHP Programming. I need to execute a python code from php. My Python code contains some external modules.
The Php code is

```
$op=shell_exec('python mgs.py');
echo $op;

?>
```

This is my intended code and i need to get the exact output as i get in terminal(if errors ,that too)

python code

```
import mechanize
def mgs():
    a=0
    flag=0
    browser = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    browser.open("http://14.139.185.88/cbcsshrCamp/index.php?module=public&page=result") 
    browser.select_form(nr=0)
    control=browser.find_control('exam_id')
    print control
    control.value=['203']
    browser.form["prn"]="130021069679"
    browser.submit()
    html = browser.response().readlines()               
    for i in range(0,len(html)):
       if 'Failed' in html[i]:                 
          flag=1
    if flag==1:
       print "Fail"
    else:
       print "Pass"



mgs()
```

. I am not getting any output on browser window, but when i tried to execute the PHP code in terminal, its fine..
ie, ( php index.php)

My OS> Ubuntu 
Apache 2

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `python` is not in the path of the user that executes your php script.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
    $op = shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 mgs.py');
    echo $op;
?>
```

Of course, change the interpreter to the correct path if this isn't the correct one.

Comment: No, I verified it, I can execute small python programs without any errors, like adding adding two numbers(pre defined

Comment: After some tests, it seems shell_exec won't return anything after an exception occurred. Try calling `mgs()` from a `try: catch:` block.

Comment: Also, you can try placing some `print` statements at the beginning of the python script, those should be printed even if an exception occurs later in the script. If it works, I'll update my answer.